# Using Tailwind Arbitrary Value Support with SCSS

Tags: webpack, sass, next.js, tailwind-css, resolve-url-loader

How to use the new [TailwindCSS Arbitrary Value Support](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support) with SCSS modules in Next.js?

The following code's CSS version was working well, but the SCSS version is throwing error:

```
// styles/foo.module.scss

.foo {
  @apply text-[#0e407c];
}
```

```
// pages/index.js

import styles from '../styles/foo.module.scss';
const IndexPage = () => <div className={styles.foo}>Hello World</div>;
export default IndexPage;
```

###### Error Log:

```
D:\foobar on main ≡ via  14.17.1
➜ rm -r .next; yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next build
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types
warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup

warn - You have enabled the JIT engine which is currently in preview.
warn - Preview features are not covered by semver, may introduce breaking changes, and can change at any time.
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

./styles/foo.module.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[3].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[3].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[3].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[3].use[4]!./styles/foo.module.scss
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1,"column":25},"source":"file://D:\\foobar\\styles\\foo.module.scss","original":{"column":null},"name":null}


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at D:\foobar\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:15:924
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\foobar\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**The error is occurring only on production builds.**

Complete repo: https://github.com/brc-dd/nextjs-tailwindcss-bug

---

##### Additional Context

###### Version Details:

```
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.3.1",
    "postcss": "8.3.6",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "sass": "1.36.0",
    "tailwindcss": "2.2.4"
```

Node.js: 14.7.1
OS: Windows 11 (22000.100)

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      autoprefixer: { flexbox: 'no-2009' },
      features: { 'custom-properties': false },
      stage: 3,
    },
  },
};
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.js']
};
```

PS: "**arbitrary-valued classes**" are not same as "**arbitrary CSS classes**" mentioned [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#limitations). The former are part of the JIT core, hence can be directly applied without any plugin or defining under `@layer` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that setting `sourceMap` option to `false` for `resolve-url-loader` does the job. Also, according to the [comments in the code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/a008d01c09773ecd7d1ae32e4e285e6d7e408055/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.ts#L58), it should be safe to do so.

Here is the `next.config.js` to override the config:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    const rules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === 'object')
      .oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));

    rules.forEach((rule) => {
      rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
        if (moduleLoader.loader.includes('resolve-url-loader'))
          moduleLoader.options.sourceMap = false;
      });
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JIT compiling make sure not to place classes with custom values  `opacity-[0.87]`  at the end of `@apply`.

```css
❌ This will not work
.class {
  @apply text-black text-opacity-[0.87];
}
✅ This will work
.class {
  @apply text-opacity-[0.87] text-black;
}
```

---

This is a caused by a bug in resolve-url-loader v2 and v3.

Comment: It does work, but what if I don't have `test-black`, i.e. I **only** have an arbitrary valued class?

Comment: Except in the case of brc-dd, this is the perfect trick.